# Mobile Emulation is not working for Chrome Version 78.0.3904.97

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Right now i am using selenium for mobile browser automation.Previously it was working fine but in Chrome Version 78.0.3904.97 it not working.
Here is my code

```
                    System.out.println("Chrome mobile Called");
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/share/chromedriver");


                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();


                    Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Galaxy S5");
                    mobileEmulation.put("width", 100);
                    mobileEmulation.put("height", 100);


                    Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

                    cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
                }
Even i upgraded to the latest chromedriver driver verison
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Is this emulation not supported? Is there any exception? Is there no action? Please correctly specify the failure.

Comment: There is no exception.Whenever i am running my mobile testcases then instead of opening mobile-chrome it opens desktop-chrome.

Comment: @demouser123 I am getting error ```INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)```

Comment: @ demouser123 thanks but i fixed the issue.The problem is with the selenium-java version.After updating it to 3.141.5 everything start working.